# Unable to update tooltip title in GWT ui binder

Tags: java, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I am trying to a add a tooltip to a button. The tooltip comes up fine. But I am able to update the title of the tooltip with my java code only in the constructor, but not in other methods. What's the issue?

```
 <b:Tooltip title="..." placement="BOTTOM" ui:field="sharedWith">
                <b:Button text="Share" 
                    type="PRIMARY" ui:field="share" icon="USER_PLUS">
                </b:Button>
            </b:Tooltip>
```

Java code:

```
sharedWith.setTitle(members.size() + " " + member);
```

sharedWith is ui:field for Tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming gwtbootstrap3 here, you need to call `reconfigure()` whenever you change properties of the `Tooltip`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the tool tip for the button programmatically, then setTitle for the button.

```
 <b:Button text="Share" type="PRIMARY" ui:field="share" icon="USER_PLUS">
                    </b:Button>
```

share.setTitle("New tool tip text");

Comment: Than, I know this, but this tooltip takes some delay to appear, while Tooltip widget has no delay, it appears as soon as mouse is over the button, that's y I chose to use Tooltip widget, instead.